# What should be the strategy for storing and clearing navigation routes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Let's look at a small example of an application working with routines. For example, in the application, navigation is handled as follows:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
    ),
  );
...
Navigator.of(context).push(
    ... ThirdScreen(),
 );
...
Navigator.of(context).push(
    ... FourthScreen(),
 );
...
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).push(
    ... FirstScreen(),
 );
Navigator.of(context).push(
    ... FourthScreen(),
 );
Navigator.of(context).pop();
...
```

I.e. there is no strict sequence in this system. Roots can be filled and cleared chaotically. Is this a problem? In other words, it is hard to predict what the final sequence will be in the navigator stack when the user closes the application. Is it a subject to worry about? Or is it a normal way of working with rooting?

Comment: For complex scenarios you can use declarative navigation instead of imperative, for example [go_router packace](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).

Answer (score 1):

I think every application has a root page eg: HomePage that is the most used page by users, let's say any social media app, the HomePage is the most used route in that app, so it's the root of the application.

So, whatever happens and wherever the user goes it stays as the root eg: (in top of the stack).

actually the above sentences based on the the nature of the app, the root page can be popped *all depends on the aimed UX*.

I'm trying to divide your question into smaller ones, you have said *there is no strict sequence in this system?*

this **sequence is called a scenario in software testing**, when your application scales up and contains many page, possible scenarios become hard to get guessed,

example:

**Suppose you have 10 routes within an app, list the possible navigation sequences?**

i think it's equal to 10! = 10 multiplied 9 multiplied 8....to 1 am i right, it's **mathematics based**.(you can exclude the root to be 9 mul 8 mul 7...)

After that, should you worry about that sequence, i think no.

As long as the HomePage in (social app example) stills in the stack, user may close the app in any stage of any different sequence, and of course we can claim that the home page stay exists.

*Roots can be filled and cleared chaotically?*

All depends on the UX which you want to make, **what do you want the user to see**

Hope it helps you.